# Cron Expression for increasing timestamps (24 hours, 72 hours, ...)

Tags: cron

Is that possible to create a cron expression which would trigger:

- 1st time at the start
- 2nd time after 24 hours
- 3rd time after 72 hours
- and then stop

I did some research on the internet, but found no solution so far. Do cron expressions have to be triggered in exactly the same intervals?